# Валидация радио кнопки в Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii, radiobutton, radio-input

В форме имеется радиобаттон.

```
<input type="radio" id="check_1" name="Deceased[style_type_id]" value="1">
<input type="radio" id="check_2" name="Deceased[style_type_id]" value="2">
<input type="radio" id="check_3" name="Deceased[style_type_id]" value="3">
<input type="radio" id="check_4" name="Deceased[style_type_id]" value="4">
<input type="radio" id="check_5" name="Deceased[style_type_id]" value="5">
<input type="radio" id="check_6" name="Deceased[style_type_id]" value="6">
<input type="radio" id="check_7" name="Deceased[style_type_id]" value="7">
```

Если не отмечать ни один из вариантов, на сервер значение не улетает, проверил.
Если отметить, на сервер прилетает значение выбранной кнопки.
В модель, в контроллере, это значение записывается, так же проверил.
Но напрочь не срабатывает валидация.
На `style_type_id` висит внешний ключ.
В справочной таблице есть значения от 1 до 7.

Правила валидации:

```
 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['relation_type_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'], 'required'],
        [['owner_id', 'relation_type_id', 'day_birth', 'month_birth', 'year_birth', 'day_death', 'month_death', 'year_death', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'status'], 'integer'],
        [['first_name', 'last_name', 'patronymic', 'birthplace', 'parents', 'education', 'family', 'carier', 'awards', 'hobbie', 'fav_animals', 'fav_places', 'burial_address'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['owner_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['owner_id' => 'id']],
        ['image', 'file', 'extensions' => 'jpg, jpeg, png'],
        [['relation_type_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => RelationType::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['relation_type_id' => 'id']],
        [['style_type_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => StyleType::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['style_type_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}
```

Остальная валидация работает.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А в чём заключается валидация? Тут что-то невидно правила для валидирования

Comment: А связь по внешнему ключу?

Comment: Все уже нашел, 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false в связь по внешнему ключу надо было прописать.